# Not able to find the magento2 database config file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, magento2

I have setup magento2 in docker container build using the docker file. Now I want to automate the database setup process so looking for the config file where I can set the database configuration like database name,username and password.

Reading few blog post says it is available at `/app/etc/env.php` but I cannot find the **env.php** file inside these location under my magento2 setup directory.

Those who are docker container for magento2, how do you automate the magento setup process (***setting up database & Creating admin account***) after magento2 installation.

Why is the env.php missing or does it comes only after initial database  set up is done once.

Answer (score 0):

The env.php file generate by magento on installation.

You can configure database and admin account during Installation process.

**Add Database configuration in installation steps**

[image: Steps to add database configuration]

**Add admin account configuration in installation steps**

[image: Configuring admin part during installation step]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following commands in a `RUN` statement in your Dockerfile:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql -e "create database magento"
sudo /usr/bin/mysql -e "create user 'magento'@'localhost' "
sudo /usr/bin/mysql -e "grant all privileges on magento.* to 'magento'@'localhost'"
```